# How to run opencv contribute-modules example in matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matlab-deployment, opencv3.1

I followed example from github:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/matlab

I want to run it in matlab :

> > I = imread('cameraman.tif');
> >     If = cv.dft(I, cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
> >     **The class cv has no property or method named 'dft'.**

I got a bug. 
I can't run well.

I would appreciate for any help.